# XSD choice of sequences

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxp

I want an element `<aaa>` to contain either a sequence of element `<bbb>` or a sequence of two elements `<bbb>,<ccc>`. For example, the following is valid:

```
<aaa>
  <bbb>
  <bbb>
</aaa>
```

and

```
<aaa>
  <bbb>
  <ccc>
  <bbb>
  <ccc>
</aaa>
```

but the following is invalid:

```
<aaa>
  <bbb>
  <ccc>
  <bbb>
</aaa>
```

I have tried the following scheme

```
<xs:complexType name="aaa">
  <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
        <xs:sequence  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="15">             
            <xs:element name="bbb" type="xxx" /> 
            <xs:element name="ccc" type="xxx"/>
        </xs:sequence> 
        <xs:sequence  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="15">
            <xs:element name="bbb" type="xxx" />
        </xs:sequence>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

but I have this error message when validating with JAXP: `cos-nonambig: bbb and bbb (or elements from their substitution group) violate "Unique Particle Attribution"` Is there a way that I can obtain my goal? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>I think that error wouldn't appear if you used XSD 1.1 (can't test it right now).</s> Edit: thanks [user Michael Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415448/michael-kay) for commenting that in XSD 1.1 the schema still have to be unambiguous, so (unlike I thought) Unique Particle Attribution error would still occur in XSD 1.1.

Anyway you can do it like the following example. Using this you're saying that the content of an *aaa* element always start with a *bbb* element, that is followed by either

*a)* from 0 to infinity *bbb* elements

or

*b)* a *ccc* element and optionaly *n* times the sequence *bbb, ccc*

```
<xs:element name="aaa">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
            <xs:element name="bbb" type="xxx" />
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="bbb" type="xxx" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="ccc" type="xxx" />
                    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:element name="bbb" type="xxx" />
                        <xs:element name="ccc" type="xxx" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: XSD 1.1 retains the Unique Particle Attribution constraint, so content models still have to be unambiguous.